# Highlighting current menu item if PHP include

Tags: php, html, include, navigation

If i make a menu nav in html and use PHP to include it in every page on my website, how do i go about highlighting the current page if all i can put on the page is include("menu.html");

Comment: Can menu.html contain PHP code?

Comment: absolutely. can be menu.php :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also write the menu in PHP since you are already using PHP to load the menu simply run an if/else statement on the menu-items to check if the "href" in the link matches the current URL of the page and set the menu item to "active".

Answer (score 10):

Make your `menu.html` into `menu.php` and within that file do something like

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li <?php echo ($page == 'page1') ? 'class="current"' : '';?>> <a href="#">Page1</a> </li>
    <li <?php echo ($page == 'page2') ? 'class="current"' : '';?>> <a href="#">Page2</a></li>   
</ul>
```

That way in each page you include your `menu.php` you can simply set the variable like so

```
<?php    
$page = 'page1';
include('menu.php');
?>
```

Keep in mind that this is just an example since we don't know what your current code looks like

Comment: Thank you - this was very helpful to me. A nice clear example.

Answer (score 3):

In raw php this should be like

```
<?php 
$currentPage = ''; // should be accessed from $_SERVER
$cssMenu = array('home.html', 'about.html');
if(array_search($currentPage, $cssMenu)) $cssMenu[$currentPage] = 'active';
?>

<ul id="top-menu">
<li class="<?= $cssMenu['home.html'] ?>">Home</li>
<li class="<?= $cssMenu['about.html'] ?>">About</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't modify classes and divs before the page loads, you'll have to use some sort of javascript/jquery/whatever to dynamically highlight the link after the page is loaded. This shouldn't be too difficult; you can have a bit of Javascript that looks through the menu div (assuming you're using divs) for an `href` entry which matches the current page, and then add the proper css class to that specific tag.